# Exact match with InStr

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with product descriptions. In the description there are various combinations.
Pack of 1, PACK OF 1, 1 PAck etc.

I have written code whereby I can configure a table of pack descriptions and sizes, to populate a field with the numeric pack size.

Table - trying to populate last column with number based on the pack found in the title
[image: Table - trying to populate last column with number based on the pack found in the title]

Pack Configuration
[image: Pack Configuration]

The code runs but it is matching PACK OF 10 in the title with Pack of 1 and putting a 1 in the end column.

I tried various combinations of the `InStr` syntax.

Is there a way to search for an exact match in the string?

The code works apart from this piece.

```vb
'Reset filter and 'Process PackSize not updated in filter process
PackListWs.Activate
ApdTbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
PLCount = PackTbl.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
SizeCount = SizeTbl.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
AmzDataWs.Activate
For i = 6 To ApdCount
   
  If Sheets("DATA - Product Validation").Range("i" & i).Value = "" Then
    If Sheets("DATA - Product Validation").Range("g" & i).Value <> "" Then
      k = 2
      For k = 2 To PLCount
        sc = 2

        For sc = 2 To SizeCount
          PackSize = PackListWs.Range("e" & sc).Value
          PackFilter = PackListWs.Range("c" & k).Value
    
          PackFilter = Replace((PackFilter), "*", PackSize)
          PackFilter = "*" & PackFilter & "*"
            
          Application.StatusBar = "Processing Amazon Pack Sizes without brackets -  " & PackFilter
          StrToChk = AmzDataWs.Range("g" & i).Value

          If InStr(1, (StrToChk), (PackFilter), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            AmzDataWs.Range("i" & i) = PackSize
          Else
            GoTo NoUpdate2
          End If

NoUpdate2:
        Next sc
      Next k
    End If
  End If
  
Next i
```

Comment: Would you be willing to try some next-level Excel stuff, like Regular Expressions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: thanks I will take a look but looks bit complicated for me

Comment: If you loop through the sizes in reverse order then then you will (eg) correctly match on 10 before it can wrongly match on 1 (make sure you exit the inner loop after making a match)

Comment: I did think of that - I am working on something that I maybe able to sell as a little product and want to try to keep it simple... I think this could be prone to user error!

Comment: I have got this working fine using wildcsrd in a filter - I am stick now on how I update just the visible cells returned... I know the value i need to updated the field with just cant work out how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to try:

```
Sub Doit()

    Dim sTest As String
    sTest = "qwerwqerqwerweqrqwer (Pack of 10)"
    
    
    Dim iLocate_PackOf As Long
    Dim sPackOf As String
    Dim aPackOf() As String
    Dim sCount As String
    Dim iCount As Long
    
    sTest = LCase(sTest) ' Set to lowercase
    sTest = Trim(Replace(sTest, ")", " ")) ' replace any right penrens with space, then trim
    iLocate_PackOf = InStr(1, sTest, "pack of ")
    
    iCount = 0
    
    If iLocate_PackOf > 0 Then
    
        sPackOf = Right(sTest, Len(sTest) - iLocate_PackOf) ' Extract "pack of XX"
        aPackOf = Split(sPackOf, " ") ' Split "pack of XX" into array
        sCount = aPackOf(UBound(aPackOf)) ' Get last element, XX
        
        If IsNumeric(sCount) Then ' If it's a number then get count.
            iCount = CLng(sCount)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good answer. Consider using `Long` instead of `Integer`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/4717755)

Comment: Oh right,...my using `integer` is a force of habit - an old habit.

Comment: thanks I will give this a go ... does the INSTR function not handle this?

Comment: also would this work if the desc was 1 x Pack?

Comment: Oh, no,...this won't work for "1 x Pack." That is not in you example sheet but I do see it in your list of descriptions.

Comment: i think I found a workaround using the Wildcard search in Filter... PackFilter = Replace((PackFilter), "*", PackSize)
PackFilter = "*" & PackFilter & "*"
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing Amazon Pack Sizes with Brackets-  " & PackFilter
    ApdTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=PackFilter, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: @NickAbbot thanks ...  The filter method does the job I am just stuck on how to populare column i for the visbible rows returned by the filter...